# pandas reshape dataframe based on repetitive values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the below pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['a',1,2,3,'a',1,2,3],1:[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80],2:[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800]})
   0   1    2
0  a  10  100
1  1  20  200
2  2  30  300
3  3  40  400
4  a  50  500
5  1  60  600
6  2  70  700
7  3  80  800
```

i want to reshape the dataframe such that my desired output should look like

```
    1    2   3    4
a  10  100  50  500
1  20  200  60  600
2  30  300  70  700
3  40  400  80  800
```

basically, i have repetitive and finite set of values in df[0] but the corresponding values in other columns are unique at each repetition. I want so unstack the table in such as way that I can get the desired output. a numpy solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: group rows by the 0th column and then convert the groups into Series.

```
df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
#    0   1
#0        
#1  20  60
#2  30  70
#3  40  80
#a  10  50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and then convert values to columns:

```
df.groupby(by=[0])[1].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.tolist())).unstack()
Out[37]: 
    0   1
0        
1  20  60
2  30  70
3  40  80
a  10  50
```

Comment: this solution does not work when the number of columns to unstack are more than one. My bad but unlike the demo data, the real data has multiple corresponding columns.

Comment: hmm, can you update your example data then @SirajS.?

Comment: updated the question to reflect the issue. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, using a dictionary to store your repetitive values and the corresponding columns, and converting it back to a dataframe. Keep in mind that dicts are disordered, so if you want to keep the order of your repetitive values you would need to tweak this a bit.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['a',1,2,3,'a',1,2,3],1:[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]})
unstacked = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.iloc[0] not in unstacked:
        unstacked[ row.iloc[0] ] = list(row[1::])
    else:
        unstacked[ row.iloc[0] ] += list(row[1::])


unstacked_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( unstacked, orient='index' )
print unstacked_df

    0   1
a  10  50
1  20  60
2  30  70
3  40  80
```